# Fastest and easiest way to get max, min, mean from multiple objects

Tags: c#, list, observablecollection

I need to find the max, min and mean (stats) value of a list of objects that have its own stats (ResultGroup class stats, based on all Result stats).
When I add objects the values are easily updated, but if I change or remove one of them, then I need to find the stats again. Usually there will be more than 40.000 items, and I need it to be a fast operation.

Is there any better way than looping through all items?

```
public class ResultGroup
{
    private Stats resultStats;
    //I need an updated stats
    public Stats ResultStats
    {
        get { return resultStats; }
    }
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Result> results = new ObservableCollection<Result>();

    public ObservableCollection<Result> Results
    {
        get
        {
            return results;
        }
    }
    public ResultGroup()
    {
        this.resultStats = new Stats();
        this.results.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(CollectionChanged);
    }

    private void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            //It works ok on add.
            Stats lastResultStat = this.results[this.results.Count - 1].Stat;
            if (resultStats.Max < lastResultStat.Max)
                resultStats.Max = lastResultStat.Max;

            if (resultStats.Min > lastResultStat.Min)
                resultStats.Min = lastResultStat.Min;

            resultStats.Mean = (resultStats.Mean * (this.results.Count - 1) + lastResultStat.Mean) / this.results.Count;
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
        {
            this.resultStats = StatsFactory();
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            //Need to find the stats here
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
        {
            //Need to find the stats here
        }
    }

    private Stats StatsFactory()
    {
        Stats dataStats = new Stats();
        dataStats.Max = float.MinValue;
        dataStats.Min = float.MaxValue;
        dataStats.Mean = 0;
        return dataStats;
    }
}

public class Result
{
    private float[] data;

    //Another class will fill data and set the Stats (max, min, mean)
    public float[] Data
    {
        get { return data; }
    }

    public Result(int lenght)
    {
        this.data = new float[lenght];
    }

    private Stats stat;
    public Stats Stat
    {
        get { return stat; }
        set { stat = value; }
    }
}

public class Stats
{
    public float Max { get; set; }
    public float Min { get; set; }
    public float Mean { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the [documentation for `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.aspx), you want to look at the `NewItems` and `OldItems` properties and recalculate based on what was added or removed.

Comment: To recalculate the mean I think I can use the old item, but max and min Its not possible.

Comment: Ah, true.  About the only way you could do that efficiently would be some sort of sorted collection that has the min at the beginning and the max at the end.

Answer (score 3):

When removing an item, you need only loop through all items, when the removed item equals the current min/max.

When replacing an item, you need only loop through all items, when the removed item equals the current min/max and the new item is greater/smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use LINQ operators like Min, Max and Average inside CollectionChanged?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can cache max, min values when you first initialize a collection, then you can compare new values with cached value.

I can suggest the next algorithm: if i had a huge list of values I would split it on the ranges and make a collection for each range. For each collection I would have a cached mean value that would be recalculated when a collection would be changed. When I add new value(or change) I would see the stats of the element and find the collection with needed range. In this situation we get a stats as additional index and we must find max and min values only in the certain collections(first, last). The mean value we could get from mean values of all collections. Max, Min values we can cache too in the first and last collections.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use DB for this ?

as DB has indexing which can help. Also have a look at KDB or SAP's HANA which has Vertical/Column based DB which makes seeping through millions of rows in milliseconds.

Maybe simple file based DB like SqlLite will help. (that should help with reducing memory usage as well if you are dealing with large amounts of data)

Answer (score 0):

//Better have a custom collection with the required properties inside the collection and then have the linq on top of the collection to store the aggregate values...

```
 public class ObserCol: ObservableCollection<int>
{

    private int _maxValue = 0;

    public ObserCol() { 
        base.CollectionChanged +=new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(CollectionChanged);
    }

    public int MaxValue{
        get {
            return _maxValue;
        }
    }

    private void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            //Can use Linq to get the Max or Other Aggregate values..
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
        {

        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {

        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
        {

        }
    }
}
```